# What are the rules of the Capture mode in Tetris: Axis?

Tags: tetris-axis

The manual for Tetris: Axis does not describe the game modes, and the single paragraph descriptions in-game are not very specific. How does one make progress in the **Capture** game mode under Party Modes? The description given is:

> Cover stars on the Matrix with Tetriminos from the "Front" and "Back" to obtain them. The high score is determined by how much time it takes you to obtain all the stars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The in-game descriptions are more extensive than they first appear. Select **Options (X)**, then **View Help**. Here there are additional screens of text (indicated by a triangle at the bottom-right) which may be accessed by pressing **(A)** or by tapping the screen.

---

To answer the original question:

To capture a star, it must be covered with the *same color* of Tetrimino from both sides.

The color of the star indicates what color covers it on the other side; early stages start out with it covered from the back so you need only cover it from the front. If a star is not covered on either side, it is white.

If you cover a star with the wrong color, the “front” and “back” matrices are exchanged, so that you start playing what was the “back” matrix. You then need to clear the occupied space of the old color and place a piece to match the color you just placed on the other side causing the flip.